# Use python to detect Excel installation

Tags: python, excel

I am using python 3.9.7. I would like to ask if there is a way python can determine if Excel is installed and also return the version number of Excel if Excel is installed.

Comment: [Get a List of Installed Softwares in Windows using Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-a-list-of-installed-softwares-in-windows-using-python/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ProgID to determine this:

```
import win32com.client

try:
    excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    version = excel.version
    print("Excel version:", version)
except:
    print("There are no excel installed")
```

There is Office 365 installed on my PC, and I get this output:

```
Excel version: 16.0
```

I also recommend you to read [this](https://pbpython.com/windows-com.html) article.

Comment: The [article](https://pbpython.com/windows-com.html) you provided says you need windows installed for pywin32 to work. What happens if someone uses Mac or Linux Os? I am using windows myself but am writing a program for others.

Comment: @KentChoo, yes it looks like a problem for multiplatform applications. In the case of Linux OS, it's easy, there is no Excel at all:) I'm unable to answer about Mac because I do not use it. However, I hope this will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164132/enumerate-all-installed-applications-on-os-x

Comment: thanks for the explanation @Tim Shidlovskii